# Stats: 'No. of posts edited' -- where do I find this?

Tags: support, editing, user-accounts, statistics

Statistics: I am not very sure where the correct, current figure for the number of posts I have 'edited' at a given time is.

The head *revisions* under *activity* on the profile page does not seem to be the one. What's the difference between *revisions* and *posts edited*, by the way?

Comment: Perhaps you mean "What's the difference between revisions and suggestions..."?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/2366/14666

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Revisions* does show posts you have revised, whether questions or answers, your own or others'. Presumably each revision is listed separately, even if you have edited a particular post more than once (it's not easy for me to find such a post to check). It's therefore likely that *revisions* is a larger number than *posts edited*. You might be able to use the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) to get figures for separate posts rather than revisions, but the data is only refreshed every so often and is not generally completely up-to-date.

*Edit:*
[A potential starter query](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/revision/161420/205823/number-of-posts-edited) — I can't remember the way of getting it to use your own UID; you need to enter it by hand.
[SEDE schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer)

That query gets a figure of 359 other-people's posts for me. `(4,5,6)` includes titles, body and tags. My *revisions* figure is 503, which indicates that (a) it includes my own revisions, of which SEDE finds 114 (359+114=473); (b) SEDE data is incomplete.

Comment: Thanks. So there's no entry in the profile, or a similar quick reference, where the figure is mentioned and updated then? (What I need to know is not the number of editing sessions but the number of posts (others, excluding my own) that I edited).

Comment: I don't think so; I'll have to have a play with the Data Explorer. I have 503 "revisions" shown in my profile, for example; it shouldn't be difficult to work out what that figure actually is, but I'm sure it does include every post edited, including my own.

Comment: Yes, it obviously does. I am having difficulty in zeroing in on the required count as above.

Comment: I had a play and revised my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just one thing remains (or it seems) -- 'other people's posts' apparently counts multiple edits. If a post is edited in two steps, it's counted as two edits (on the same post). No way to discover/filter this.

Comment: The `distinct` keyword should distinguish that and count only unique posts.

Comment: True. I overlooked that. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I just examined my own (very limited) **activity** set. It seems that

- **suggestions** is a list of edits that I proposed but did not have authority to make real — they had to be judged by others with enough reputation. (The judgements are discoverable.)
- **revisions** is a list of edits that I made — either to my own posts (requiring no other approval) or elsewhere (and were approved). The edits were realized.

I don't know if *posts edited* is an "official" term/title or not.